# display multiple images show in one row for single product in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

How to display multiple images for single product in View file like table single they has one row contains three images how to return result from model.?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by creating the model for your Users. The simplest way would be to create single method inside model with sql join, but I prefer to have separated methods for different types of data.

```
    class User_model extends CI_Model {
        public $User_id;
        public $Lname;
        public $Fname;
        public $Timestamp;

        public function __construct($id = null){
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function getUserByID($id){
            $query = $this
                         ->db
                         ->from('Users')
                         ->where('User_id', $id)
                         ->get();
            $results = $query->result();
            if(count($result) > 0){
                return $result[0];
            }
        }

        public function getUserPicturesByID($id){
            $query = $this
                         ->db
                         ->from('Images')
                         ->where('User_id', $id)
                         ->get();
            $results = $query->result();
            if(count($result) > 0){
                return $result;
            }
        }


        public function getAllUserDataByID($id){
            $query = $this
                         ->db
                         ->from('Users')
                         ->join('Images', 'Users.User_id = Images._User_id')
                         ->where('User_id', $id)
                         ->get();
            $results = $query->result();
            if(count($result) > 0){
                return $result[0];
            }
        }

    }
```

You can autoload model by adding model name to application/config/autoload.php file or you can load model from your controller.

```
    $this->load->model('User_model');
```

Then you can call model methods in your controller like this

```
    $user = $this->User_model->getUserByID(1);
    $userPictures = $this->User_model->getUserPicturesByID(1);
```

and pass data to the view like this:

```
    $data = array(
             'user' => $user,
             'pictures' => userPictures 
            );
    $this->load->view('user_view', $data);
```

... and in your view you can access the data like this:

```
    echo $user->Fname;
```

or pictures in foreach loop:

```
    foreach($pic in $pictures){
        echo '<img src="', $pic->ImagePath, '" />';
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @siniša-dragičević-martinčić